# SOLVED - Access a folder after publish in azure dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net, azure, publish

I have to reference FolderX in my application after publish/deploy in Azure... The folder FolderX is in my publish Folder, but everytime I try access get me a error: "Directory not found: \n/home/site/FolderX !"

I have the following code in my csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="FolderX\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Now, I have to reference FolderX in my application after publish/deploy in Azure... The folder FolderX is in my publish Folder, but everytime I try access get me a error: "Directory not found: \n/home/site/FolderX !"

Since in my publish Folder, "FolderX" is in the same level of wwwrot, I try reference FolderX in this way:

```
string filePath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + @"\"; //pick a path "wwwrot" and return 1 folder
string filePath2 = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
string DiretorioSchemas = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath2) + "/FolderX";
```

But It's continues give me a error: "FolderX not found!". Where am i going wrong?

---

EDIT: Thanks @rahularyansharma

Resolve:
[Get XML comments output file location for ASP Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36691004/get-xml-comments-output-file-location-for-asp-core)

Note: dotnet 6.0 removed this lib, so for this implementation a nugget must be downloaded.

```
string basePath = Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.ApplicationEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath;
string folderPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "FolderX");
```

Comment: Is your application hosted in Azure App Service ?

Comment: Hi, yes... It was hosted in Azure App Service

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36691004/get-xml-comments-output-file-location-for-asp-core

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me... Note: dotnet 6.0 removed this lib, so for this implementation a nugget must be downloaded.

For me:
```string basePath = Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.ApplicationEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath;

 string folderPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "FolderX");```